# How to figure out Google Sheet query #N/A error(only when open)

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, spreadsheet

I have two sheets: One listing sales (named ‘Aug’ for August) and one listing product information (named ‘PRef’).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eFXblUjEeusJOXU6bLSu922RnhEs45NZVJm8hM-pXdw/edit?usp=sharing

From my link above there's an error when I open the sheet in column E. If I delete and fill the same value to the same cell the formula works, so my formula is correct. How can I figure it out? It is so annoying.

My query:
`=QUERY(Pref,"select C where A like "&C2&" and B like "&D2&" limit 1",0)`

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: He was doing a query.

Comment: @eaksit-buathong-iem: I know from having seen the file that your problem was an SQL problem. To improve your question (and earn reputation from it), please update your question, preferably including a copy of the faulty query and a description of where the query is and whence you are collecting data. As you can see from both the answers you got, we understand your problem (from having opened your spreadsheet) and have provided the same working solution for you. Without opening your links, users will not be able to know this is an SQL question. Questions should be as self-contained as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two errors in your query:

1. Your sheet name has a full stop: It is ’PRef.’, not ‘PRef’, so either change the name of the sheet or the data call line.
2. You forgot to call which columns you want to collect data from. Changing it to `=QUERY(PRef.!A:E` yielded the desired result, as per the image.

[image: Image calling the data as desired.]

Those pesky missing punctuations are always going to cause errors, so it is always good practice to avoid the possibility for such to happen.

The query is on the format `=QUERY([datasheet]![data area]`. If you forget to define the data area, the query doesn’t know where to collect the data.

## Edit 10 August 2021

I had another look at your database, and tried tweaking the query a bit. For some reason, I do not know why, Google Sheets doesn’t seem to like `like` very much; changing it to `=` instead, completely solved the problem.

```
=QUERY(GoodsList,"select C where A = "&C2&" and B = "&D2&" limit 1",0)
```

I renamed the area with the goods to GoodsList, so I could simply reference that. Apart from that, the only difference is that I replaced `like` with an equals sign and I removed the unnecessary single quotes. Screenie:

[image: Image of working database, with query slightly modified to account for the limits of Google quasi SQL language.]

Note that `limit 1` is absolutely needed, otherwise you will get `#Ref` errors, as it is trying to write to a cell that is populated by a query hit.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. The Pref in my formula is named range for my data.
As you can see in two link below.
https://ibb.co/pQZLZxG
https://ibb.co/xsrpdXC
The same formula give different outcomes. It errors when reloaded but can work again when delete and reentered the same formula

Comment: Again, the name of your sheet is ‘PRef.’ – that is pee-ref-and-a-full-stop – not ‘PRef’ and no full stop. I opened your link, copied the sheet and fixed the error, as you can see in the screenie.

Comment: Still the same problem. The formula is work but the error occurs only when reload page. And work again after delete and enter it again. https://ibb.co/Gd1mFG7

Comment: It should be working well now. @EaksitBuathong-iem.

Answer (score 0):

Within your query, instead of `PRef`, use `PRef.!A:C`.

It might be more efficient to use `arrayformula` and `lookup` instead of all the `query`.

Try this in cell `E2` (deleting all content below `E2`):

```
=arrayformula(if(C2:C<>"",vlookup(C2:C&"|"&D2:D,{PRef.!A:A&"|"&PRef.!B:B,PRef.!C:C},2,0),))
```

[image]

You can also add an `iferror` when there is no match:

```
=arrayformula(if(C2:C<>"",iferror(vlookup(C2:C&"|"&D2:D,{PRef.!A:A&"|"&PRef.!B:B,PRef.!C:C},2,0),"Not found"),))
```

Comment: Beat me by six minutes. I shouldn’t have taken the time to write so much. ;-)